# SUMIF over an area of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table structure similar to this.

[image: table structure]

I'm no trying to find a formula to sum up all cells in columns `B` and `C` where the corresponding value in column `A` is, e.g., `x`.

Using `SUMIF()` works fine when I just want to sum over a single column (`B` or `C`) in this case:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5,"x",B1:B5)
```

However, when I try the same over a range of columns like this.

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5,"x",B1:C5)
```

it still sums only over the first column (`B` in this case) and not the entire range.

Any suggestions?

The expected result for the above example (summing for `x`) should be `33` and not `3` as the above formula returns.

<sup>Sidenote: The actual use case contains way more columns to sum over. So, just adding individual `SUMIF()`s gets quite cumbersome.</sup>

Comment: Use `SUMPRODUCT()` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of <kbd>SUMIF( )</kbd> or <kbd>SUMIFS( )</kbd> use <kbd>SUMPRODUCT( )</kbd> or <kbd>SUM( )</kbd> which works with arrays

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:C5)*--(E2=A1:A5))
```

---

Or,

```
=SUM((B1:C5)*--(E2=A1:A5))
```

Comment: I had experimented with `SUMPRODUCT()` as well, but for whatever reason it didn't work. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: @Sirko is it working now, may be you need to hit `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` based on your excel version, but usually it doesnt require.

Comment: Nice answer. You can leave out the -- if it's part of an arithmetical expression like a multiplication and it will convert true/false to 1/0 automatically i.e. =SUMPRODUCT((B1:C5)*(E2=A1:A5))

Comment: @TomSharpe Sir, agree with you.